# Bots can't be created from Xcode Server hosted repository

Tags: xcode, git, ssh, xcode-bots, xcode-server

After creating a new repository on my `Xcode Server`, I can't access it by *ssh*, but I can perform both the `git clone` command and the `git push` command by using the *https* protocol.

Furthermore I encounter the following error when I try to create a *Xcode Bot*:

```
Oct 25 12:43:46 mokii.com xcsbuildd[99898]: XCSCheckoutIntegrationStep.m:160 [XCSCheckoutIntegrationStep logUnderlyingErrorForError:]
    [SourceControl, Error] SSL error: received early EOF (-1)
Oct 25 12:43:46 mokii.com xcsbuildd[99898]: XCSCheckoutIntegrationStep.m:119 [XCSCheckoutIntegrationStep enqueueOperations]
    [SourceControl, Error] Error checkout/clone Error Domain=com.apple.dt.SourceControlErrorDomain Code=-1 "SSL error: received early EOF (-1)" UserInfo=0x7fcf244d3cd0 {com.apple.dt.sourcecontrol.UnderlyingErrorString=SSL error: received early EOF (-1), NSLocalizedDescription=SSL error: received early EOF (-1)}
Oct 25 12:43:46 mokii.com xcsbuildd[99898]: XCSIntegrationExecutor.m:229 [XCSIntegrationExecutor integrationStep:didFinishWithError:result:]
    [BuildService, Error] XCSCheckoutIntegrationStep finished integration with an error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.SourceControlErrorDomain Code=-1 "SSL error: received early EOF (-1)" UserInfo=0x7fcf23e117f0 {com.apple.dt.sourcecontrol.UnderlyingErrorString=SSL error: received early EOF (-1), NSLocalizedDescription=SSL error: received early EOF (-1), XCSErrorFixItType=scm-failure}
```

When I try to execute the `git clone` command the hosted repository in `Terminal.app`, another error occurs:

```
larryhou:repo larryhou$ git clone ssh://jason@mokii.com/git/HostedRepo.git
Cloning into 'HostedRepo'...
Password:
fatal: '/git/HostedRepo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

And I can find additional information in the `Console.app`:

```
 Marker - Oct 25, 2014, 12:25:13 PM
Oct 25 12:25:15 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Oct 25 12:25:15 mokii com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.4EA7979A-127B-452C-832D-3A9A7FCB5A04): Service instances do not support events yet.
Oct 25 12:25:16 mokii.com kdc[380]: AS-REQ jason@MOKII.COM from 127.0.0.1:62481 for krbtgt/MOKII.COM@MOKII.COM
Oct 25 12:25:16 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Oct 25 12:25:16 mokii.com kdc[380]: Client sent patypes: REQ-ENC-PA-REP
Oct 25 12:25:16 mokii.com kdc[380]: user has no SRP keys
Oct 25 12:25:16 mokii.com kdc[380]: Need to use PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP/PA-PK-AS-REQ
Oct 25 12:25:16 mokii.com kdc[380]: AS-REQ jason@MOKII.COM from 127.0.0.1:58943 for krbtgt/MOKII.COM@MOKII.COM
Oct 25 12:25:16 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Oct 25 12:25:16 mokii.com kdc[380]: Client sent patypes: ENC-TS, REQ-ENC-PA-REP
Oct 25 12:25:16 mokii.com sandboxd[508] ([380]): kdc(380) deny file-read-data /private/etc/krb5.conf
Oct 25 12:25:16 mokii.com kdc[380]: ENC-TS pre-authentication succeeded -- jason@MOKII.COM
Oct 25 12:25:16 mokii.com kdc[380]: DSUpdateLoginStatus: Unable to synchronize login time for jason: 77009 
Oct 25 12:25:17 mokii.com kdc[380]: Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, des3-cbc-sha1, arcfour-hmac-md5, using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96/aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
Oct 25 12:25:17 mokii.com kdc[380]: Requested flags: forwardable
Oct 25 12:25:17 mokii.com kdc[380]: TGS-REQ jason@MOKII.COM from 127.0.0.1:60555 for host/mokii.com@MOKII.COM [canonicalize, forwardable]
Oct 25 12:25:17 mokii.com kdc[380]: TGS-REQ jason@MOKII.COM from 127.0.0.1:59504 for host/mokii.com@MOKII.COM [forwardable]
Oct 25 12:25:17 mokii.com kdc[380]: TGS-REQ jason@MOKII.COM from 127.0.0.1:49478 for ldap/mokii.com@MOKII.COM [canonicalize, forwardable]
Oct 25 12:25:17 mokii.com kdc[380]: TGS-REQ jason@MOKII.COM from 127.0.0.1:58173 for ldap/mokii.com@MOKII.COM [forwardable]
Oct 25 12:25:17 mokii.com sshd[61715]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for jason from 192.168.2.3 port 58668 ssh2
Oct 25 12:25:17 mokii.com sshd[61722]: Received disconnect from 192.168.2.3: 11: disconnected by user
Oct 25 12:25:17 mokii com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.4EA7979A-127B-452C-832D-3A9A7FCB5A04[61715]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
```

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Could not find a solution for this problem so far. The link to apple dev forum contains only me too answers unfortunately. With this issue xcode server pretty much becomes useless :(

Comment: i've run into this issue several times, but since i moved to https, I've been able to checkout, just not push.  I used this blog post to get me through some of my issues, maybe it will help you as well http://papaanton.com/setting-up-xcode-6-and-apple-server-4-0-for-continues-integration-with-cocoapods/

Comment: Git problems are mostly because of the SSH or SSL issues. In order to make the git clone work, you might need to replace the git:// link with https link.

Answer (score 1):

You have got the SSH URL all wrong. You cannot use SSH simply by replacing the protocol and leave the URL in the same form as HTTPS. Here is a step by step guide for using SSH with Git on XCode Server and setting up the bots:

http://ikennd.ac/blog/2013/10/xcode-bots-common-problems-and-workarounds/

One more that is a bit newer and might be more accurate:

https://honzadvorsky.com/articles/2015-08-04-xcs_tutorials_1_getting_started/